Firefox can't reach mdns .local names with more than two labels (local fake subdomains)
Fake MDNS subdomains like aaa.mypc.local work with any Chrome based browser but not with Firefox.
Firefox can reach hostname.local and extra .local names like myservice.local but not more than two label names (separated with a dot, which means subdomain in DNS world).
In order to facilitate some local web development, I recently configured my Linux machine (Ubuntu 22.04) to broadcast some extra .local names via a python package mdns-publisher like explained here Using MDNS aliases within your home network.
Why not modifying /etc/hosts ? Because with this method I can access the webserver from any computer on the local network without having to modify /etc/hosts on each which would be annoying in case of IP change or name change or adding new names.
I don't want to configure a proper DNS server either.
It works and after a little configuration I'm able to reach my pc with extra .local names like this:
ping mypc.local # original hostname.local name
ping website1.mypc.local # fake subdomain for hostname.local
ping website2.mypc.local # also fake subdomain for hostname.local
ping someservice.local # extra unrelated name

Client side, I had to create a file /etc/mdns.allow containing
.local.
.local

because otherwise, more than two labels names would be rejected like explained here.

If the request has more than two labels, it is rejected. Example: foo.bar.local is rejected. This is the two-label limit heuristic.

I also modified /etc/nsswitch.conf like this (adding 'mdns4') to make it work properly with extra names:
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns

Great, I can reach my local webserver which will handle multiple websites via request headers.
I tried to set Firefox's option network.dns.native-is-localhost to true but then the browser is offline for external websites.
Any idea on this ?
